# Clojure:Why is Ref Lost on Assoc

Tags: clojure, ref, stm

I am working on updating counters in a map ref in Clojure.

```
(defn increment-key [this key]
    (dosync
        (let [value (get @this key)]
            (if (= value nil)
                (alter this assoc key (ref 1))
                (alter this assoc key (alter value inc))))))
```

However, it looks like the alter value inc statement is losing the reference:

```
(defn -main [& args]
    (def my-map (ref {}))
    (increment-key my-map "yellow")
    (println my-map)
    (increment-key my-map "yellow")
    (println my-map))
```

Which prints:

```
$ lein run
#<Ref@65dcc2a3: {yellow #<Ref@3e0d1329: 1>}>  
#<Ref@65dcc2a3: {yellow 2}>
```

How can I keep the same reference while updating it in this scenario?

Comment: Hate to be that guy, but is possible to show a before and after of what it is you are attempting to do? You say "update key" but the output looks like it is incrementing the value. Perhaps I've been staring at too much javascript lately, but the the "this" atom scares me a bit.

Comment: Sure thing.  Actually the before and after is in the function `-main` above.  I start with an empty ref, then increment the value associated with a key "yellow" with `increment-key`.  `this`, in this case, is not a special form, `this` have been called `my-object-ref`.

Comment: I started browsing a bit and noticed you have 2 other threads on this very subject. What is different here that you are attempting to solve that those threads don't tell you and why are you not using the same ideas they showed you? I think you are misinterpreting what "state" and "immutability" means and you may want to read up on it. Read this entire chapter and you will be enlightened: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-19.html#%_chap_3

Comment: actually, this is about the loss of the ref even though I used alter.  did you attempt to run or understand what is going here, or are you just naysaying?

Comment: I know you are working hard to understand this, but I promise that you are way way way over-thinking this issue. Also, there would be no new anything because there is no such thing as "value" like you have here: (alter value inc), although there is a "val" in Clojure. Maybe try val and see if it does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there. Below is the solution, check the last line of `increment-key`, you just need to alter the value (not alter the key in the map as you were doing, coz that was causing the key to be updated with the alter return value which in you example was 2, remember alter returns the new value of the ref, not the ref itself). Also don't use def inside a def, you should use let (in your -main function)

```
(defn increment-key [this key]
    (dosync
        (let [value (get @this key)]
            (if (= value nil)
                (alter this assoc key (ref 1))
                (alter value inc)))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (let [my-map (ref {})]
       (increment-key my-map "yellow")
       (println my-map)
       (increment-key my-map "yellow")
       (println my-map)))
```